# Call PartialView via Ext.Net.ComponentLoader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to render some Partial Views into the main View. So i used the Ext.Net.ComponentLoader like this:

```
@(
        Html.X().Window()
            .Title("Items")
            .Width(400)
            .Height(300)
            .Closable(false)
            .Resizable(false)
            .Layout(LayoutType.Border)
            .Items(i=>{
                i.Add(new Panel{
                    ID = "West1",
                    Title = "West",
                    Width=200,           
                    Layout = "Accordion",         
                    Region = Region.West,                    
                    Loader = Html.X().ComponentLoader()                        
                        .Url(Url.Action("WestItems"))                        
                        .Mode(LoadMode.Script)
                        .Params(new { containerId = "West1" })
                });

                i.Add(new Panel{
                    ID = "Center1",
                    Region = Region.Center,
                    BodyPadding = 10,
                    Header = false
                });
            })
     )
```

the main view here is calling Partial View with action controller `"WestItems"` which is not good in my case. i want to call partial View directly without action controller like using `Html.Partial("_PartialView", Model)` also i want to send the Model as parameter to the partial view. Is there any way to call Partial View directly via ComponentLoader? How to send Model as parameter to the Partial View?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857923/ext-componentloader-lazy-loading-htmljs-within-component

Comment: @Yogiraj i dont need to create another function. I m looking for the right syntax to be used instead of Url(Url.Action("WestItems"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should always call controllers action and they will render partial views.
Partial view are called like:

```
public PartialViewResult _PartialView(string containerId)
        {
            ...
             return new PartialViewResult
                {
                    RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
                    ContainerId = containerId,
                    Model = yourModel,
                    WrapByScriptTag = false 
                };
            }
        }
```